# VirtualHost & Proxy with Location

Tags: apache2, docker

So I have a docker/nodejs daemon running with an imager located at port 3030. This code below works fine for when accessing imager.mydomain.online to reach the correct folder. The folder contains a index.js and the scripts for it.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName imager.mydomain.online
ServerAlias wwww.imager.mydomain.online
ServerAdmin admin@admin
DocumentRoot /var/www/imager/dist
 <Directory "/var/www/imager/dist">
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
 </Directory>
ErrorLog error.log
CustomLog access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem comes when I try to add this code below the end Directory for

```
<Location "/">
    ProxyPass http://172.38.0.2:3030/
    ProxyPassReverse http://172.38.0.2:3030/
    RequestHeader set Host $host
    RequestHeader set X-Real-IP %{REMOTE_ADDR}s
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-For %{HTTP_PROXY_ADD_X_FORWARDED_FOR}s
</Location>
```

So what I'm trying to do is to make it connect to the daemon at port 3030 but when I add the code above I cannot restart apache2.

I have installed mod_proxy with a2enmod